# Fill DIV with list items

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fill a `<div>` with list-items so that when the items reach the `max-height` of the `<div>` they start again from the top, but a little bit more on the right? (See attached image)

[image: List-Example how I want it to be!]

Comment: Some of the `display: inline`-stuff but i don't know how to make it vertical...

Comment: Post the code you've tried, then it's easier to help based on your approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can use the following code

```css
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
   li::before{
    content:'- ';
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px;height:300px;max-height:300px;overflow:hidden">
 <ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I Added a ::before the li so you can have the dash before it

Comment: thanks, done it with `::before` and `content: "\2022";`. That's a really good answer man!

Comment: The pain in the arse thing about this is that when I need to do something like this in the future I will probably forget about `column-count` and `column-gap`.

Comment: then to prevent a pained arse better remember this.